# Is discoloration in my basement wall framing a concern?

Tags: wood, basement, framing, moisture, timber-framing

We have a leak in our foundation, so I opened up the wall to patch it. This section of the wall comes to a T, and when I cut off the 2x4, I noticed discoloration in roughly 35-40% of the 2x4 that proceeds into the next room over, on the other side of this wall. Is this something to be concerned about? I'm just learning how to do all of this. I can push a nail about 1/10 or so of an inch into the discolored part, but not at all in the colored part.

Do I need to continue taking this wall down? Should I remove the whole T section to see if the damage continues, or am I exaggerating this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://imgur.com/a/R82419V

Comment: Foundation leaks are recommended to fixed/repair/sealed from the outside where the water comes from.  Inside DIY repairs/sealing should be consider temporary only, months to a couple of years.  Is the wood dry or feels damp/wet?

Comment: It looks like the wood may have absorbed some water, but not much and I don't see any additional water damage. You still have some time to fix the source of the leak and then replace the wood. It seems to still be "good" for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

This looks fairly trivial considering the apparent age of the structure. That looks like some pretty ancient wood (though you haven't told us anything about your house's age or location). We can assume that it's been damp at least once, but that's not a disaster. The question is whether you've resolved the moisture problem.

If it's not mushy it's fine.

Comment: It's not a huge concern.  I've seen much worse rotted wood in my own basement.  Try one of the injectable foundation repair kits.  You epoxy the surface of the crack and attach ports, then inject a highly viscous polyurethane that expands throughout the crack.